# Can't create block: "Use of a block which no longer exists"

Tags: ev3

> ```
> Unable to compile some documents for deployment:
> Program.ev3p: Use of a block which no longer exists.
> PutInRange.ev3p
> ```

The block I want to make. It will put a input value inside a given range.
When I try to upload i always get a error. I already deleted every thing and started new. And always it will give me a error. The Lego software looks very buggy to me. Am I the only one that has these problems ?

[image: This is the block i want to create]

This is the MinValue block that gives the minimal value of two.

[image: MinValue]

This is the MaxValue block that gives the maximal value of two.

[image]

And this are the blocks in my program, and there all there.

[image]

Comment: Can you upload the project so I can test it by myself? I've heard the error message before but I'm not quite sure what the solution was. Maybe if I can test with it there's a chance I remember the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting(saving locally) the block that shows error. Then delete it from the program and import it from where you saved it